# Wicked_PDF/wkhtmltopdf different font and page width sizes from pdfs in different controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Setup: Rails 4.1.1 application using `gem 'wicked_pdf', '~> 0.11.0'` and a manually installed wkhtmltopdf binary version 0.12.1 (with patched qt)

I have two controllers generating similar pdf reports which share several pages. I have partials for the pages that are shared between the two report types.

## controller code:

```
# GET /assessments/1
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf:          "Individual_Report-#{Date.today}",
             disposition:  "inline",
             layout:       "pdf",
             dpi:          "300",
             encoding:     "UTF-8",
             show_as_html: params[:debug].present?
    end
  end
end

# GET /reports/1
def show
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.pdf do
      render pdf:          "Team_Report-#{Date.today}",
             disposition:  "inline",
             layout:       "pdf",
             dpi:          "300",
             encoding:     "UTF-8",
             show_as_html: params[:debug].present?
    end
  end
end
```

## view code:

```
# layouts/pdf.slim
doctype html
html
  head
    meta charset="utf-8"
    title
      = content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : 'Main Title'
    == wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => 'all'
    == wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "print", :media => 'all'
    == wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'vendor/modernizr'
    == csrf_meta_tags
  body data-action=action_name data-controller=controller_name data-format="pdf"
    main
      == yield
    == wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag 'application'
    javascript:
      window.jQuery || alert("false");

# assessments/show.pdf.slim
= render "shared/cover", m: @assessment, t: "Individual"
= render "shared/about"
= render "shared/team", report: @report
# etc. etc. this is where the reports differ

# reports/show.pdf.slim
= render "shared/cover", m: @report, t: "Team"
= render "shared/about"
= render "shared/team", report: @report
# etc. etc. this is where the reports differ
```

However the report from the assessments controller is generating a pdf that has a slightly narrower content width and accordingly smaller text size. Rendering the html with the debug param gives identical pages and inspecting the css shows no differences. I'm using Foundation as a css framework but I don't think that is important.

I read some about wkhtmltopdf's `--disable-smart-shrinking` option but I'm not sure if that is used by wicked_pdf and if so, how to/if it can be changed in the wicked_pdf.rb initializer. I also set the dpi and different values to no effect. Adjusting the page margins helps some but doesn't fix the underlying issue. I can add screenshots if needed but I think the problem should be clear enough without them.

Thanks for any help on how to fix the issue or adjust wkhtmltopdf options using wicked_pdf.

Answer (score 1):

I figured this one out by accident. It seems the issue was being caused by something else I was doing with Chart.js and a < canvas > element that was sized larger than it's container.

I don't precisely understand what was causing the issue. It may have also been connected to some CSS from the Foundation framework which I am also using. Nevertheless, I'll post this answer in case it helps others solve the same issue.

I won't accept this as the answer since it doesn't specifically answer the question and doesn't address how to

> "adjust wkhtmltopdf options using wicked_pdf."

If anyone else can reply to that I'll accept it.